# Как подставить в js скрипт карты готовые координаты из поля

Tags: javascript, координаты, данные

Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, меня, ребенка в программировании, этот вопрос ставит в тупик. У меня есть сайт недвижимости на wordpress. У каждого объекта есть географические координаты:

1.В скрытых полях ACF
2.Вспециально выведенном в каждом объявлении поле.

Выведенное поле на странице является элементом списка (

). И я целый день потратил на то, чтобы координаты центра карты брались из этого поля. Ничего я не добился. Уже можно сказать js скрипту все подготовил - бери да вставляйся :)))

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
ymaps.ready(init);
function init(){
var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
center: [44.554968,33.529025],
zoom: 15
});

}
</script>
```

Вот пример страницы: https://cvetoch.ru/properties/kvartira-32-kv-m-3/

Как подставить это поле, где уже прописаны широта и долгота? Когда копирую его значение и вставляю вместо координат, все работает. Вот целый день коту под хвост - такую мелочную проблему решить не могу.

Спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы не можете вытащить координаты локализации со страницы?

Comment: let listInnerText = document.querySelector('.mh-estate__list__inner').innerText;
let localizationMatch = listInnerText.match(/Локализация: [\d\.]+,[\d\.]+/);
let coordinatesArray = []; 

if (localizationMatch !== null) {
    coordinatesArray = localizationMatch[0].split(': ')[1].split(',');
}

Comment: Низкий поклон Вам и дай Бог здоровья! Сейчас буду пробовать применить Ваш код в скрипте! От всего сердца благодарю!

Comment: Уж простите, Вы и так мне уже готовое решение дали. А у меня все равно мозгов не хватает: не могу понять, а в какое место скрипта карт код надо вставлять, чтобы его результаты появились в center: [сами координаты]?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
let listInnerText = document.querySelector('.mh-estate__list__inner').innerText;
let localizationMatch = listInnerText.match(/Локализация: [\d\.]+,[\d\.]+/);
let coordinatesArray = [];
if (localizationMatch !== null) { coordinatesArray = localizationMatch[0].split(': ')[1].split(','); }
 
        ymaps.ready(init);
        function init(){
            var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                center: [.coordinatesArray],
                zoom: 7
            });
        }
    </script>

Comment: Так выглядит код моей карты сейчас. Понимаю, что это неправильно, но ни навыков, ни как таковых знаний у меня попросту нет....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var listInnerText = document.querySelector('.mh-estate__list__inner').innerText; 
        var localizationMatch = listInnerText.match(/Локализация: [\d\.]+,[\d\.]+/); 
        var coordinatesArray = []; 
        
        if (localizationMatch !== null && localizationMatch > 0) { 
            stringCoordinatesArray = localizationMatch[0].split(': ')[1].split(',');
            coordinatesArray = stringCoordinatesArray.map(item => parseFloat(item));

            ymaps.ready(init); 
        
            function init() { 
                var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", { 
                    center: coordinatesArray,
                    zoom: 7 
                });    
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Простите, до последнего не хотел Вам писать, чтобы не огорчать человека, который уже много сделал. Но... Вместо карты просто пустой белый div отображается...

Comment: А вы выполнили шаги из документации по [яндекс картам API](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/quick-start/index.html#get-api-key)?

Comment: Конечно. Я же до этого делал те карты, в которые вручную вписывал координаты...

Comment: Мне из Яндекса прислали скрин, что координаты не получены. Не знаю, как прикрепить его сюда.

Comment: А это они написали: "Беглый взгляд на инициализацию карты показал, что не сработал поиск координат. в поле координат. Дальнейшим дебагом вам следует заниматься самостоятельно, это не относится непосредственно к работе API."

Comment: Проблема полностью решена! Огромнейшее Вам спасибо еще раз! Храни Господь!